# Why jquery works after reloading once in Angular 7 project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, angular7

I have a dashboard created with angular 7 CLI this uses bootstrap, but the main functions are writed in jquery like every template i know. The problem is the next one:
[image]

For toggle the sidebar the html uses this line
`<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="navbar--btn" data-toggle="sidebar" title="Toggle Sidebar"></a>`
jquery file contains this code for that:

```
    var $toggleSidebar = $('[data-toggle="sidebar"]');

    $toggleSidebar.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $body.toggleClass('sidebar-mini');
    });

    var $scrollBar = $('[data-trigger="scrollbar"]');

    $scrollBar.each(function() {
        var $ps, $pos;

        $ps = new PerfectScrollbar(this);

        $pos = localStorage.getItem('ps.' + this.classList[0]);

        if ($pos !== null) {
            $ps.element.scrollTop = $pos;
        }
    });

    $scrollBar.on('ps-scroll-y', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('ps.' + this.classList[0], this.scrollTop);
    });
```

The problem here is when i pass from the login to this dashboard with routing `{useHash:true}`, the toggle button not work after i reload one time the page.
Another one is the scrollbar in the sidebar... not appear until i refresh one time. Exists anyway to avoid the reloading for this type of `[data-trigger]` or `[data-toggle]` in Angular 7?

Comment: It is not a recommended practice to use jquery with Angular. See this article: https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/jquery-future-angular-react-vue/ and this discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/92lpy4/reasons_not_to_use_jquery_angular/

Comment: Yes i know that, but the template have this code for doing basic functions like toggle the sidebar or initialize the scrollbar. How to use that in angular?

Comment: Toggling anything is usually done with an `*ngIf`. I'm not sure exactly what you are doing with the scroll bar ... if you are displaying a new route it should "initialize" automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone, i solve it with a `location.reload(true);` in the auth service.
The problem is, when i access from login to the dashboard i was doing a "redirection" to the dashboard and when i sign out i redirect to login with [routerLink]="" when the auth.service do the redirection this confuses the system. For every one with the same problem don't do the redirection twice. Greetings!

Comment: where did you put this ?